# react-datepicker sets initial date to 01-01-1970

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, momentjs

I am trying to create a date field via react-datepicker with the initial date set to today.
I'm using react-datepicker and moment.js.

Problem is, that my date initially is 01-01-1970 and not today's date.

Here is my code:

```
   <DatePicker
        dateFormat="DD.MM.YYYY"
        selected={this.convertTimestampToDate(this.props.event.startDate)}
        onChange={this.handleStartDayChange}
    />
```

and:

```
private convertTimestampToDate(ts: number): any {
        return moment(ts);
    }
```

and:

```
private handleStartDayChange(selectedStartDay: any) {
    this.setState({
        selectedStartDay: selectedStartDay,
        selectedEndDay: this.state.selectedEndDay
    });
    this.props.onUpdateEvent(updateEventStartDate(this.props.event, selectedStartDay.valueOf()));
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `this.props.event.startDate`?

Comment: id: string;
    startDate: number;
    endDate: number;
    image: Image | null;

Comment: I'm interested in its **value**, not data type.

Comment: there is no difference to selected={this.state.startDate} as in the documentation i guess

Comment: Okay, let me put it this way. startDate is a number, yes? What is the number?

Comment: sorry, im no web pro. maybe i misunderstand you. start date initially is just a number which is sent to my Event after the input and stored on a mobile preview. does that answer your question?

Comment: Right. That number, is it 5? 996134? 5542? What's the number?

Comment: its a timestamp. so more letters than 1 i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Created the date via moment.js. 
that solved my problem.

Comment: What if the date is empty? In this case I also recieve a default date: 01/01/1970

Comment: I'm also receiving 1970 as a default date. I using MS fluent UI Date Picker and the property of value needs to be used to set the state. In my case I can't use new Date() for the value property!